# Is this code breaking strict-aliasing rules?

Tags: c, type-punning

I have a large buffer that represents a 3D model file loaded and decompressed from a HDD, the file has a header and some vertex, index and subset data after it. At first i thought i could calculate byte offsets where each vertex/index/subset data begins and simply cast it to a compatible pointer type and use it, but this would break strict-aliasing rules. So an solution would be to memcpy bytes to separate vertex/index/subset data arrays (each array of different type ofc)?

```
unsigned char *buf = NULL;
size_t offset = 0;

/* ... */

/* now @buf points to data immediately following the file header */

/* copy mesh subsets list */
memcpy(out->subsets, buf, sizeof(*out->subsets) * header.num_subsets);

/* copy vertex indices list */
offset = sizeof(*out->subsets) * header.num_subsets;
memcpy(out->indices, &buf[offset], sizeof(*out->indices) *
        header.num_indices);

/* copy mesh vertices list */
offset += sizeof(*out->indices) * header.num_indices;
memcpy(out->vertices, &buf[offset], sizeof(*out->vertices) *
        header.num_vertices);
```

Comment: What makes you think it could break aliasing rules?

Comment: strict aliasing does not apply if a pointer is of type char

Comment: @ouah I don't really know, i wasn't sure how to make this model loader to work without invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Aliasing is never relevant for modifications that are done through a function call, `memcpy` included. Here the compiler must always assume that the object might have changed through the call.

Comment: @bolov So as long as the bytes are valid (e.g., 4 bytes make a meaningful float) i am safe right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attacking the strict aliasing rules from the wrong angle. Casting an array of `char` to your structure would in fact be UB. This is not only because of aliasing but also because alignment properties can be different. Don't do that.

You'd have to do it the other way round: declare your structure of the real type that you want to have, and then use a `void*` or `char*` pointer to that structure to read or copy your data into it.

This is always guaranteed to work:

- character types are exempted from the strict aliasing rules
- passing a pointer of an object to a function (`memcpy` or other) always ensures that the compiler can't make any assumptions about the state of that object after the call, so he has to reload the entire object.

*Edit:* Perhaps some the confusion comes from the strange gcc warning about "aliasing rules".  This is only one facet of the problems that come from type-punning through pointer casts. Generally accessing an object through a pointer of a wrong type other than character types can have undefined behavior. Aliasing is only one of several things that can go wrong with that. Just avoid it.

Comment: You made this comment in OP question: *Aliasing is never relevant for modifications that are done through a function call*. Any Standard references to support this? So for example `void f(float *a) { *a = 0; } void g(void) { int x = 0; f((float *) &x); }` from your comment, `f` call does not break aliasing rules?

Comment: @ouah, accessing an object through a pointer of different type (other than character types) is UB. Aliasing is not the problem in your example.

Comment: So what do you meant exactly by *Aliasing is never relevant for modifications that are done through a function call*? Could you give an example without using functions from the Standard library?

Comment: After you pass a pointer of an object to a function that might "legally" modify the object the compiler must assume that such a modification may have taken place. So after such a function call, all aliasing considerations that concern that object so far are irrelevant, it must be reloaded from memory, anyhow.

Comment: @JensGustedt: You are allowed to mix int*/unsigned int*, long*/unsigned long* etc. if the values fit (int must be positive, unsigned int must be small enough to fit into int). Not allowed to mix int* + long* even if int and long are both 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with casting your `char*` to a pointer to your structure is not strict aliasing rules: `char` types are exempted from strict aliasing rules. That is, you may read data written as `char` data as any other type, and you may conversely read any data as char data.

The problem with the cast is alignment. Unless you have obtained your `char*` directly from a memory allocation function (which is guaranteed to produce a pointer sufficiently aligned for any data), you risk misalignment, which can crash your program. Using `memcpy()` works around this. However, if you can be certain that your `char*` is perfectly aligned, there is no need for the copy.

To avoid confusion, this is perfectly legal code:

```
typedef struct Foo {
    ...
} Foo;

void bar() {
    char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
    fillBuffer(buffer);
    Foo* header = (Foo*)buffer;    //Ok, buffer is a perfectly aligned pointer.
    readHeader(header);    //Ok, reading data written as char data does not violate strict aliasing rules.
}
```